# Answer to this double integral while solving for flux without using symmetry

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^L\int_0^L\frac{dy \text{ }dx}{(\sqrt{l^2+x^2+y^2})^3}$$

I tried solving it the normal way by keeping y constant first, plugging in the limits then solving the integral and that yielded me
$$\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{L^2}{l\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}\right)}{l}$$

But when i tried doing it using polar coordinates (i did it just to be sure), i converted the integral into
$$2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_0^{L\sec{\theta}}\frac{r}{(l^2 + r^2)^{3/2}} dr d\theta$$
which ended up to
$$\frac{\pi}{4l}-\frac{\arcsin(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}})}{l}$$

For context, I was trying to solving for the flux through square plate without using symmetry (which is basically brute force) and ended up here. Some help on what would be the correct would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have not fully checked your end results but I think it has something to do with $$
\cos\theta=\sin(\theta+\tfrac\pi 2)=\tfrac l{\sqrt{l^2+L^2}}\,,\quad\sin\theta=\tfrac L{\sqrt{l^2+L^2}}\,,\quad
\tan\theta=\tfrac Ll\,.
$$
$$
\theta=\arctan(\tfrac Ll)=\arcsin(\tfrac l{\sqrt{l^2+L^2}})-\tfrac\pi 2\,.
$$

Comment: They must be the same. Cumbersome work even with Wolfram Alpha. Check your calculations again. In the worst case use python and test numerically.

Comment: @KurtG. I get what you're trying to say with the interconversion of arctan and arcsin but it the pi/4 is what's tricking me and I don't know how I would be able to check it numerically using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to show that they're the same (I multiplied by a factor of $2$ to the polar solution because it wasn't the same result):
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{L^2}{l\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}\right)}{l}&\overset{!}{=}\frac{\pi}{2l}-\frac{2\arcsin\left(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}}\right)}{l}\\
\frac{L^2}{l\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}&=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arcsin\left(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}}\right)\right)\\
&=\text{cotan}\left(2\arcsin\left(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1-\tan^2\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}}\right)\right)}{2\tan \left(\arcsin\left(\frac{l}{\sqrt{2(l^2+L^2)}}\right)\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-\left(\dfrac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}\right)^2}{2\dfrac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}}=\frac{1-\dfrac{l^2}{l^2+2L^2}}{2\dfrac{l}{\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}}=\frac{l^2+2L^2-l^2}{2\dfrac{l(l^2+2L^2)}{\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}}=\frac{L^2}{l\sqrt{l^2+2L^2}}\ \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: I forgot to multiply with the factor of 2 while solving using polar, thank you for pointing that out.